# Java Null Pointer Exception, how can i fix that?

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

I'm in trouble with that thing.

```
public class Money {
          String girl ;
          Money mon ;
      public void sorry (){
          mon.girl = "Isabel" ; //I want to do that (here is basic part) but...
                                //..I get Null Pointer Exception
      }
}
```

How can i fix that problem? I really need the solve, if you'll help me I appreciate that guys.

Comment: You need to instantiate mon with new operator

Comment: As you are trying to access the variable from the same class use : `girl = "Isabel";`

Comment: yes you declared mon, but it is null unless until you initialized it that is why you are having NPE

Comment: don't have an instance variable of the Class 's type within the class. that's asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks Stultuske, it's helping me.

Answer (score 1):

reolace your code with

```
public class Money {
          String girl ;
          **Money mon = new Money();**
          mon.girl = "Isabel" ; //I want to do that (here is basic part) but...
                                //..I get Null Pointer Exception
     }
```

It was due to not initializing the object `Money mon` .

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the Money object before set any property.

```
Money mon = new Money();
```

Moreover, it seems it's to simplify, but your code looks strange :

**Definition**

```
public class Money {
   String girl ;
}
```

**Usage**

```
Money mon = new Money();
mon.girl = "Isabel" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must need to initialize i.e need to create a instance of object `Money` before use.

Try to initialize it in this way.

```
public class Money {
          String girl ;
          Money mon = new Money(); // created instance for Money.

          mon.girl = "Isabel" ; 
     }
```

Comment: but this is something you really don't want to do.
it'll be a recursive call to the Money constructor, crashing the application within seconds